# Improve the use of advanced search options

Tags: feature-request, search

I have looked at certain combinations of search keywords, and I've found that using the keywords is difficult. Could it be possible to implement something similar to Google advanced search so that it would be easier?

*The keywords I am referring to are, e.g.,created:..2020-07-31,intags:mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those keywords/options *should* work (but do use spaces between them).

Yes, Stack Exchange search is far from perfect, but I'm not sure if the company wants to put much energy in duplicating Google. They've already revamped the search bar (with the tooltip showing some special search terms), they're focusing on other topics right now.

What you can do is using *Google* to better search Chess Stack Exchange. Google (and other search engines) have a special search operator to limit your search to a single site:

```
site:chess.stackexchange.com
```